# Y-axis is very crowded in matplotlib,How do I hide y-axis values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I want to plot 1000 values on y-axis and 1000 values on x-axis,but my y-axis gets very crowded and I can't see any number clearly.How do I resolve this? 
Note: I want to plot all 1000 values but want to display every tenth y-axis value on the y-axis.
 [Graph I a referring to,You can see the crowded y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywaRP.png)

Comment: Do not plot strings. Plot numbers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is:

yticks()

You might want to pass a numpy array to yticks, between the values you want shown.

Check out this documentation for matplotlib.pyplot.yticks():
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks